# Center Map by using googlemap-places API

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I programmed a website (based on html, css) that makes possible to search for doctors in a specified place (at this time from a Database/SQL).
I also wanted to include a map, that visualizes to the user the doctors around him.

So I did some experiments witch GoogleMaps-Places-API and other APIs but my programming-Skills are to bad to do this / understand what to do!

I need a Map that can spot the user and center on him - and set a marker at his position. After the user has defined a searching-area the map should switch to this position and show all doctors (maybe filtered by subject of doctor).

Would the best way to do this would be to use my PHP input field (for database-request) and connect it with the map?

The first script is my experiment-map. It centers but doesn't set any place markers around the user.

The second script is my php request to communicate with the sql database.

```js
<script>
var map;
var stepDisplay;
var service;


function initialize(coords) {
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude);
 var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

       
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlng,
  map: map,
  title: "Hier bist du :)"
});
}

 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
 initialize(position.coords);
}, 
 function(){
 document.getElementById('map_canvas').innerHTML = 'Deine Position konnte leider nicht ermittelt werden';
 });


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

```html
<?php
   
   //Datenbank einbinden
   include("config.inc.php");
   
   if (logged_in()) header('Location: http://localhost/n_a_h.php');
   
   $con = mysqli_connect(host,user,pass) or die ("Fehler beim Verbinden mit der Datenbank!");
   mysqli_select_db($con, database) or die ("Fehler beim &Ouml;ffnen der Datenbank");
   
   echo "<form action = '' target='_self' method = 'post' name='fachr' target'_self'>";
   
    //Auswahl Fachrichtung
    echo "Fachrichtung: ";
    echo "<select name='ps_fachrichtung'>";
    echo "<option value=''>Bitte w&auml;hlen...</option>";
      
    $sql_fr = "select fachrichtung from t_fachrichtung";
    $res_fr=mysqli_query($con, $sql_fr);
      
    while ($dsatz_fr = mysqli_fetch_array($res_fr))
    {
     echo "<option>".$dsatz_fr["fachrichtung"]."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
     
    //Auswahl PLZ Ort
    echo "PLZ / Ort: ";
    echo "<id='ps_plz_ort'><input name='ps_plz_ort' />";
    
    echo "<input type = 'submit' name = 'ps_senden' value='Best&auml;tigen' size ='20' />";

   echo "</form>";
   
   //ablauf der Suche
   if (isset($_POST['ps_senden']))
   {
    //Ausgewählten Fachbereich anzeigen
    $ps_fr = $_POST["ps_fachrichtung"];
    $ps_plz_ort = $_POST["ps_plz_ort"];
    preg_match("(\d+)",$ps_plz_ort,$ps_plz);
    $ps_ort=explode(" ", $ps_plz_ort);
    $lg=count($ps_ort);
    
    
    $ps_plz_kon="no";
    for ($i=0; $i<$lg; $i++)
    {
     if (is_numeric($ps_ort[$i]))
     {
      //$ps_plz[0]=$ps_ort[$i];
      if ($i==0) $k=1;
      else $k=2;
      $ps_plz_kon="yes";
      break;
     }
    }
    $ps_ort[0]=implode(" ",$ps_ort);
    //echo "$k<br />";
    //echo "$ps_plz_kon<br />";
    if ($ps_plz_kon=="yes")
    {
     if ($k==1) $ps_ort[0]=substr($ps_ort[0],6);
     else  $ps_ort[0]=substr($ps_ort[0],0,-6);
    }
    //echo "<br />";
    //echo $ps_plz_ort;
    //echo "<br />";
    //echo $ps_plz[0];
    //echo "<br />";
    //echo $ps_ort[0];
    echo "<br />"; 
    echo "Fachbereich: ";
    echo "$ps_fr<br />";
    
    //Ärzte suchen und anzeigen
    if ($ps_plz_kon=="no")  
    {
     $sql_erg = "select * from t_arzt where A_Fachrichtung = '$ps_fr' AND A_Ort = '$ps_ort[0]'";
    }
    else    
    {
     if ($ps_ort[0]=="") $sql_erg = "select * from t_arzt where A_Fachrichtung = '$ps_fr' AND A_PLZ = '$ps_plz[0]'";
     else    $sql_erg = "select * from t_arzt where A_Fachrichtung = '$ps_fr' AND (A_Ort = '$ps_ort[0]' OR A_PLZ = '$ps_plz[0]')";
    }
    $res_erg = mysqli_query($con, $sql_erg);
    $num_erg = mysqli_num_rows($res_erg);
    
    switch($num_erg)
    {
     case ($num_erg == 0):
      echo "Es wurden keine &Auml;rzte in Ihrer N&auml;he gefunden.<br />";
      break;
     case ($num_erg == 1):
      echo "Es wurde ".$num_erg."  Arzt in Ihrer Umgebung gefunden.<br />";
      break;
     case ($num_erg >= 2):
      echo "Es wurden ".$num_erg."  &Auml;rzte in Ihrer Umgebung gefunden.<br />";
    }
    //if ($num_erg==0) echo "Es wurden keine &Auml;rzte in Ihrer N&auml;he gefunden.<br />";
    //else echo "Es wurde(n) ".$num_erg."  &Auml;rzt(e) in Ihrer Umgebung gefunden.<br />";
    
    if ($num_erg > 0)
    {
     echo "<br/>";
     echo "<table border width='50 %'>";
      echo "<tr align='center'>";
       echo "<td><b>Praxis</b></td>";
       echo  "<td><b>Adresse</b></td>";
       echo "<td><b>Wartezeit</b></td>";
      echo"</tr>";
      while ($dsatz_erg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_erg))
      {
       //echo $dsatz_erg["A_Titel"]." ".$dsatz_erg["A_Nachname"].", ".$dsatz_erg["A_Vorname"].", ".$dsatz_erg["A_Strasse"]." ".$dsatz_erg["A_Hausnr"].", ".$dsatz_erg["A_PLZ"]." ".$dsatz_erg["A_Ort"]. "<br />";
       echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$dsatz_erg["A_Titel"]." ".$dsatz_erg["A_Nachname"].", ".$dsatz_erg["A_Vorname"]. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$dsatz_erg["A_Strasse"]." ".$dsatz_erg["A_Hausnr"].", ".$dsatz_erg["A_PLZ"]." ".$dsatz_erg["A_Ort"]. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$dsatz_erg["A_Wartezeit"]." min</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
      }
     echo "</table>";
    }
   }
  ?>
  
        <!-- <p class="Text">Praxis Suchen</p> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It matters less if you use PHP (or any other server side programming language) or jQuery or a JSON document to feed markers to your markers array

Try this snippet (I've tested it):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var mapObj;

function initialize() {

    var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

    var mapObj = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Try HTML5 geolocation
    if(navigator.geolocation) 
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) 
        {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                    map: mapObj,
                                    position: pos,
                                    content: 'Deine Position'
                                });
            mapObj.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() 
        {
            var options = {
                           map: mapObj,
                           position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
                           content: content
                        };
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
            mapObj.setCenter(options.position);

        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    }

    var infowindow  = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var markers = []; //array to hold markers
    // Multiple Markers
    markers.push(['London Eye, London', 51.503454, -0.119562]);
    markers.push(['Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633, -0.124755]);

    // Loop through your array of markers and add them to mapObj  
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
    {
        //create a latitude / longitude object first:
        var pointLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1],markers[i][2]);  

        //extend map to include new marker
        bounds.extend(pointLatLng);

        //create the marker object:
        markerObj = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: pointLatLng,
                            map: mapObj,
                            title: markers[i][0]
                        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(markerObj, 'click', (function(markerObj, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent("info window: "+ markers[i][0]);
                        infowindow.open(mapObj, markerObj);
                    }
            })(markerObj, i));

        // center map fitting all markers on the screen
        mapObj.fitBounds(bounds);
        markerObj.setMap(mapObj);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

You'll then work with the  array to store your markers data. Hope this makes sense.

Note that there is also an option to code addresses should you not have access to latitude and longitude of a desired marker:
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addressString}

Comment: Ok Thank your so far.
But everytime I paste those Script-Snippets in my Script nothing works anymore.

Maybe someone give me a complete solution that works, pls?

Comment: Ok it works!
But, at this time it set markers first at some places and after that it centers on my position.
The function that I need is that it centers first on my position and after I write down a town in the php-input-field it set markers in this area in about 500m around or sth.

Comment: go for whatever means you want to feed locations into the markers array: `markers.push(['Some title', Latitude, Longitude]);` (use `mapObj.setCenter(LatLongObj);` to center map) and then initialize the maps again.

Comment: Ah now i Know:
I dont want to mark defined positions on my map - I want to Use the googleMap-Places library . If you write down "doctor London" to google it jumps into a map and show doctors in london (centered of the middle of london f.e.) . Thats the function I need!

And it should get his information from my php-input-field ...
that doesn`t even works!

Comment: Would you please help me further?